# Are there any standards regarding email and password acceptable and unacceptable characters?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, pop3

What are the acceptable characters set that can be used in any email and password for authentication over any of the following protocols:

```
SMTP 
POP3
IMAP
```

Simply what is acceptable and what is not

can i use my own rules, does everyone do so, and is there a W3C reference? i did some research but couldn't find any.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard which governs this. Consult the documentation for the implementations you are using. I would expect they will accept any sequence of bytes verbatim (and then users who log in from a device which transmits UTF-8 where they previously used e.g. Latin-1 will be locked out if these two representations differ).

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your replay, i have checked the documentation for theses 3 protocols, none of them mentioned any restriction regarding the password characters set

Comment: You'd best stick to printable ASCII.  Traditionally, these protocols use unix password systems which generally just use a "bunch of bytes" for matching, but there's no standard for encoding unicode.  Most software will probably use latin-1 or utf-8, but for interoperability, I would avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three protocols reference SASL for this, the Shared Authentication and Something Layer. Security perhaps.

SASL regulates authentication, and allows the use of different authentication mechanisms whose syntax and semantics are shared where that makes sense. RFC 4616 specifies one common method and [its page 3 has the answer you're looking for](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616#page-3): Passwords may be up to 255 bytes long when encoded using UTF8, any unicode character is permitted except 0, and [some characters are equivalent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4013#section-2). For example, several space characters are mapped to ASCII space.

Mechanisms are permitted to be stricter. For example, the SASL mechanism that builds on Microsoft's NTLM authentication will include both Microsoft's and SASL's restrictions. That doesn't matter in a protocol sense. IMAP/SMTP clients cannot really tell the difference between a too-long password and a mistyped password.